# Android: custom icon not displayed in ActionBarDrawerToggle of DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am trying to implement `DrawerLayout`. The drawer layout is working fine. But the icon displayed in Top Left corner is `android.R.id.home`. However I have mentioned my custom icon in `ActionBarDrawerToggle` as follows:

```
// Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
    drawerLayout = (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);



    // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            **R.drawable.icon_top_menu**, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when drawer is closed */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        } 

        /** Called when a drawer is opened */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_top_menu);
    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your onoptionsItem selected, should missing there...............

as shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}   

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

in place of '.action_settings' try 'icon_top_menu' your icon.......

Comment: Hi Mayank, I tried as you said, but it's not working. The problem is that I have BaseDrawerActivity which contains the Drawer layout code. There are other activities which extends this BaseDrawerActivity. For the first case only, I am having this issue. The icon ("android.R.id.home")doesn't change as expected. When you click on that icon, the drawer layout comes out and for all other Activities functionality is working fine. I am very much surprised why is this issue coming for the very first time. Any suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you should use visibility true/false for the icon menu in each activity where you want to show your icon...and please describe your question properly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

To 
user1182217

okay i got your problem some what, hope this will help you.

as for icon id you are using "android.R.id.home" which is 'android id' by default,
in place of that use your icon id as R.id.home/ R.id.your_icon_id hope the only error as 
per your problem description..........